# Magento - how to get email address via order/customer_id

Tags: magento

How do I get the customer email address in Magento? Eventually I wish to export all shipment details in CSV format.

```
<?php
    //External script - Load magento framework
    require_once("app/Mage.php");
    Mage::app('default');

    $myOrder=Mage::getModel('sales/order'); 
    $orders=Mage::getModel('sales/mysql4_order_collection');
    $allIds=$orders->getAllIds();
    foreach($allIds as $thisId) {
        $myOrder->load($thisId);
        echo "name: ". $myOrder->getShippingAddress()->getFirstname() . " " . $myOrder->getShippingAddress()->getLastname();
        echo "email: " . $myOrder->getPayment()->getOrder()->getEmail();
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: echo "name: ". $myOrder->getShippingAddress()->getFirstname() . "|" . $myOrder->getShippingAddress()->getLastname();                  This does not give me the name from the the first line of the address. Any suggestions to extract the name?

Answer (score 24):

You can use:

```
echo "name: ". $myOrder->getCustomerName();
echo "email: " . $myOrder->getCustomerEmail();
```

(tested in magento 1.6.2.0)

Comment: these methods work starting since the version 1.6.2.0 to 1.9.1.0 included!

Answer (score 1):

As I recall, the email adress is also stored with the Shipping/Billing information, so:

```
$myOrder->getShippingAddress()->getEmail()
```

Comment: Hmmm, could you try $myOrder->getCustomerEmail()

Comment: You should probably not run an outdated version like 1.4, due to security issues.

Comment: I would never run magento 1.4, but the customer don't want to upgrade, unfortunately :-(

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code to avail email address via order customer ID:

```
 $orderId = '100000023'; // mention order id here
    $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($orderId);
    $shippingAddress = $order->getShippingAddress();
    echo $shippingAddress->getEmail();
```